# Find Registry key name based on a value? PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to find the registry key name based a value. In the key value, it has string (REG_SZ) like "Version22.r2" (Name of this String value is "*Version*"). I have this under a specific path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\xxxxxx. So, I want to look for the value "Version22.r2" under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft, if it is found, I want to find the key name (xxxxx).

Tried, it gives no output (what am i missing?!)
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_ -like "*Version22.r2*"}).PSChildName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to discover all the relevant keys, then use `Where-Object` nested in `Where-Object` to inspect the string values attached to each and only filter in those keys that have at least one such value:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ -Recurse |Where-Object {
  # assign current key to a local variable so we can reference it later
  $key = $_
  # now filter all the attached values based on type and content
  @($key.GetValueNames() |Where-Object {
    # first test that the value is a string ...
    $key.GetValueKind($_) -eq [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String -and 
    # ... and then inspect the value
    $key.GetValue($_) -eq 'Version22.r2'
  } |Select -First 1).Count
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Get-ChildItem : Cannot call method. The provider does not support the use of filters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ -Recurse |Where ...

Comment: @Azure_CloudServices That's a surprising error message given that we didn't specify any filters :) What version of PowerShell are you using (`"$($PSVersionTable['PSVersion'])"`), and does it stop raising the error if you remove `-Recurse`?

Comment: 22621  2506    

same error even after removing `-recurse`

Comment: @Azure_CloudServices Try `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft` instead of `HKLM:` as the OP seems to want. This does not explain the strange error message about filters though..

Comment: @Azure_CloudServices Did you mean to post `5.1.22621.2506` in your previous message? You're using Windows PowerShell on Win11 23H2?